How to terminate watchdog process if the utility status is active in Python tkinter app?
I have a tkinter Python app where I am checking the utility status from the API on entering the email address. If the utility status is active I want to terminate the watchdog process. If the status is not active then the watchdog process will run. If I close the app window the watchdog process kicks off and the app restarts again which if fine.
The issue is if I close the app with alt+f4 or with task manager it restarts the process which is also fine, but when I enter the email and the users' utility status is active then the app should be terminated and not restart again via the watchdog process.
How to achieve this?
import keyboard
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests
import re
import os
import sys
import time
import subprocess

# Global variable to control watchdog process and app closing
watchdog_active = False
process = None
app_closing = False

def block_keys():
    # Blocking Win+D
    keyboard.add_hotkey('win+d', lambda: None, suppress=True)
    # Blocking Alt+Tab
    keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+tab', lambda: None, suppress=True)
    # Blocking Win+Tab
    keyboard.add_hotkey('win+tab', lambda: None, suppress=True)
    # Blocking Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+esc', lambda: None, suppress=True)

def unblock_keys():
    # List of hotkeys to unblock
    hotkeys = ['win+d', 'alt+tab', 'win+tab', 'ctrl+shift+esc']
    
    # Unblock each hotkey if it's currently registered
    for hotkey in hotkeys:
        if hotkey in keyboard._hotkeys:
            keyboard.remove_hotkey(hotkey)
        else:
            # print(f"Hotkey {hotkey} is not registered.")
            return True
        
# Watchdog process function (simulation)
def start_watchdog():
    global watchdog_active, process
    watchdog_active = True
    print("Watchdog process started")
    
    app_name = "test2.py"  # Replace with your actual app filename

    while watchdog_active:
        # Check if the app is running
        if process is None or process.poll() is not None and watchdog_active:
            # App is not running or closed, restart the app
            print("App closed. Restarting the application...")
            process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, app_name])
        
        time.sleep(5)  # Check every 5 seconds

def terminate_watchdog():
    global watchdog_active, process
    print("Watchdog process terminated")
    watchdog_active = False  # Stop the loop in start_watchdog()
    
    # If the process is running, terminate it
    if process is not None:
        process.terminate()
        process = None

# Function to close the application
def close_app():
    global app_closing
    print("Closing the application")
    app_closing = True  # Indicate that the app is being intentionally closed
    terminate_watchdog()  # Terminate the watchdog process before closing
    sys.exit()
        
# Function to validate email format
def is_valid_email(email):
    # Regex pattern for a basic email validation
    pattern = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$'
    return re.match(pattern, email) is not None        

# Simulating an API call to check password validity
def check_password_with_api(password):
    api_url = "http://localhost/utilitysoftwareapp/api/check-default-password"
    # api_url = "https://utilitysoftwareapp.levenex.in/api/check-default-password"
    response = requests.post(api_url, data={'password': password})
    response_data = response.json()
    
    return response_data['status']

# Simulate an API call to check if a user exists based on the email
def check_user_exists_with_api(email):
    # Validate email format before proceeding
    if not is_valid_email(email):
        print("Invalid email address!")
        return False, None
    
    # Proceed with API call if email is valid
    api_url = "http://localhost/utilitysoftwareapp/api/check-user-exists"
    # api_url = "https://utilitysoftwareapp.levenex.in/api/check-user-exists"
    response = requests.post(api_url, data={'email': email})
    response_data = response.json()

    return response_data['exists'], response_data['utility_status']

# Simulate an API call to register a new user
def register_user_with_api(name, email):
    api_url = "http://localhost/utilitysoftwareapp/api/save-user-info"
    # api_url = "https://utilitysoftwareapp.levenex.in/api/save-user-info"
    response = requests.post(api_url, data={'name': name, 'email': email})
    response_data = response.json()
    
    return response_data['status']

# Function to handle password submission
def check_password():
    entered_password = password_entry.get()
    if check_password_with_api(entered_password):
        show_email_screen()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Incorrect password, try again.")

# Function to check if a user exists
def check_user():
    email = email_entry.get()

    # Validate email format
    if not is_valid_email(email):
        # Display a message box with an error if email is invalid
        messagebox.showerror("Invalid Email", "Please enter a valid email address.")
        return
    
    exists, utility_status = check_user_exists_with_api(email)
    
    if exists:
        if utility_status == "active":
            messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You have an active utility. Closing the application.")
            unblock_keys()
            root.quit()
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Info", "No active utility. Locking the screen.")
            lock_screen()
    else:
        show_registration_screen()

# Function to handle registration
def register_user():
    name = name_entry.get()
    email = email_entry.get()
    
    if register_user_with_api(name, email):
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Registration successful!")
        show_email_screen()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Registration failed. Please try again.")

# Function to lock the screen if no active utility
def lock_screen():
    # Check if the lock label already exists
    if not hasattr(root, 'lock_label'):
        root.lock_label = tk.Label(root, text="System is locked.", font=("Arial", 20))
        root.lock_label.pack(pady=20)
        block_keys()


# Function to show the email entry screen
def show_email_screen():
    clear_screen()
    
    email_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your email address:", font=("Arial", 20))
    email_label.pack(pady=20)
    
    global email_entry
    email_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=("Arial", 20))
    email_entry.pack(pady=20)
    
    check_button = tk.Button(root, text="Check", command=check_user, font=("Arial", 20))
    check_button.pack(pady=20)

# Function to show the registration screen if user doesn't exist
def show_registration_screen():
    clear_screen()
    
    name_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your name:", font=("Arial", 20))
    name_label.pack(pady=20)
    
    global name_entry
    name_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=("Arial", 20))
    name_entry.pack(pady=20)
    
    email_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your email address:", font=("Arial", 20))
    email_label.pack(pady=20)
    
    global email_entry
    email_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=("Arial", 20))
    email_entry.pack(pady=20)
    
    register_button = tk.Button(root, text="Register", command=register_user, font=("Arial", 20))
    register_button.pack(pady=20)

# Utility function to clear the screen
def clear_screen():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

# Create the main application window
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)  # Make the window fullscreen
root.title("Levenex utility App")

# Create a label and entry for the password
password_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter your password:", font=("Arial", 20))
password_label.pack(pady=20)

password_entry = tk.Entry(root, show="*", font=("Arial", 20))
password_entry.pack(pady=20)

# Create a button to check the password
submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=check_password, font=("Arial", 20))
submit_button.pack(pady=20)

# Block the win+d, win+tab, alt+tab, ctrl+shif+esc 
block_keys()

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()

# Block the win+d, win+tab, alt+tab, ctrl+shif+esc 
# Block the win+d, win+tab, alt+tab, ctrl+shif+esc 
unblock_keys()

# Adding watchdog integration

import threading
import time

# Function to check the utility status
def get_utility_status():   
    global app_closing
    try:
        email = email_entry.get()
        api_url = "http://localhost/utilitysoftwareapp/api/check-utility-status"
        response = requests.post(api_url, data={'email': email})
        response_data = response.json()
        app_closing = True  # Mark utility status as checked
        return response_data['utility_status']  # Assumed to be 'active' or 'inactive'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching utility status: {e}")
        return 'inactive'

def main():
    global app_closing

    # Don't check utility status if the app is being closed
    if not app_closing:
        # Check utility status every time
        utility_status = get_utility_status()

        if utility_status == 'active':
            print("utility is active. Terminating watchdog process and closing the app...")
            terminate_watchdog()  # Terminate watchdog when utility status is active
            close_app()  # Close the application
        else:
            print("utility is inactive or an error occurred. Watchdog remains active...")
            start_watchdog()
    else:
        print("App is closing, skipping utility status check.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`

I have achieved one of the points which I wanted. The app closes on first time when the utility status is active. The issue occurs after closing the app with alt+f4 or task manager then when after the app is restarted via the watchdog process it should close if the utility status is active. It closes the window but restarts again.
